# Facebook login from server side

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to login with facebook from server side (Java, php, asp...)?
What i have found till now envolves a popup dialog and a redirect_uri. What i want is to call a login url from my server code and take the response in JSON format for example (or plain, or xml...)

I have read the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) but no luck

Comment: No, there is no way of doing that (at least no official way). Users are not supposed to give their credentials to 3rd parties, but login through Facebook themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in to Facebook uses OAuth, which requires a user to be present, so the actual log in is not possible only from the server side. However, using the token you obtained with OAuth does not require a user.